# How to send a textbox as a parameter for KeyDown function c#?

Tags: c#, function, parameters, textbox

I have 10 textbox. I want a common KeyDown function so that I can send a parameter when I call it. I input some text in textbox1 and press "Enter" Key then cursor focus the send textbox(for example: textbox2) which I send as a parameter in time of KeyDown function call.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read the [help] and in particular [ask]

Comment: Uh. Pretty much all Listeners in C# _already contain_ an `object sender`...

Comment: @Nyerguds I think he is saying that on `textBox1`'s on lick event, he wants to pass a textBox other than itself, for example `textBox2` as a parameter

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Pretty impossible unless it's a fixed order to rotate through; in that case the answer is to simply put them all in some global array and check which one you're currently at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by Dmitry Bychenko has the basis you need. But if you want to always select the *next* textbox, you'll first need some kind of list of that order and fill it in your class constructor:

```
private TextBox[] textBoxOrder;

public Form Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBoxOrder = new TextBox[]
    {
        textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5,
        textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9, textBox10
    };
}
```

Then in your key listener, you can do the following to select the next one:

```
TextBox nextBox = null;
for (Int32 i = 0; i < textBoxOrder.Length; i++)
{
    if (textBoxOrder[i] == sender)
    {
        if (i + 1 == textBoxOrder.Length)
            nextBox = textBoxOrder[0]; // wrap around to first element
        else
            nextBox = textBoxOrder[i + 1];
        break;
    }
}
if (nextBox != null)
    nextBox.Focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `TextBox` instance is sent via `sender` parameter:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // if we can focus:
        //   1. it's a textbox instance that has called Key Down event
        //   2. the textbox can be focused (it's visible, enabled etc.)  
        // then set keyboard focus  
        if ((textBox != null) && textBox.CanFocus) 
        {
            textBox.Focus();
            // you may find useful not proceeding "enter" further
            e.Handled = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure, that you've assigned the *same* `textBox1_KeyDown` method for *all* textboxes of interest (`textBox1`...`textBox10`)